# How to find least square fit for two combined functions

Tags: curve-fitting

I have a `curvefit` problem

I have two functions

```
y = ax+b
y = ax^2+bx-2.3
```

I have one set of data each for the above functions

I need to find a and b using least square method combining both the functions

I was using `fminsearch` function to minimize the sum of squares of errors of these two functions.

I am unable to use this method in `lsqcurvefit`
Kindly help me

Regards
Ram

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to worry less about which library routine to use and more about the math. Assuming you mean vertical offset least squares, then you'll want

```
D = sum_{i=1..m}(y_Li - a x_Li + b)^2 + sum_{i=j..n}(y_Pj - a x_Pj^2 - b x_Pj + 2.3)^2
```

where there are m points (x_Li, y_Li) on the line and n points (x_Pj, y_Pj) on the parabola. Now find partial derivatives of D with respect to a and b.  Setting them to zero provides two linear equations in 2 unknowns, a and b.  Solve this linear system.

Answer (score 1):

> y = ax+b
>
> y = ax^2+bx-2.3

In order to not confuse y of the first equation with y of the second equation we use distinct notations :

> u = ax+b
>
> v = ax^2+bx+c

The method of linear regression combined for the two functions is shown on the joint page :

[image]

HINT : If you want to find by yourself the matrixial equation appearing above, follow the Gene's answer.